# Dynamic dependency checking tool for Java

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, guice, dynamic-analysis

I'm looking for a tool that analyses and optimises my dependency hierarchy in my Gradle projects. I've already taken a look at https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze and on this one coming from Netflix https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin. Both do the job based on static analysis of the compiled classes. Nevertheless, anything that is based on reflection can't be found using static code analyse tools, thus injection frameworks will fail and the analysis will yield results for dependencies the static code is not using while the running code will be.

So are there tools that can be used? I'm thinking about something like some code coverage tools do based on running unit tests. Any ideas are highly welcome!